# Namespaces tree javascript example and explanation of syntax

Tags: javascript, javascript-namespaces

Namespaces tree javascript example and explanation of syntax.

This namespaces to be defined in javascript:

1. root
2. root.person
3. root.home
4. root.home.relative

my try that wrong:

```
var root='';
root.person='';
root.home='';
root.home.relative='';
```

Please explain your code I not know js well as php/c/java

Thanks

Comment: Probably better answered by reading through: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/881515/javascript-namespace-declaration as AlexJones mentioned below.

Answer (score 3):

JavaScript has no concept of "namespaces" in the sense of Java etc. Instead we use good old objects, and add attributes to those objects.

If `root` is to be your "*namespace*", we define `root` as an object, and define the members of the namespace as **members** on the object ("person", "home", "relative").

To declare an object (for `root`), the easiest way is to use [**object literal syntax**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript_syntax#Creating_objects)

```
var root = {
    person: 'Jim',
    home: 'London'
}
```

You can nest objects using this syntax as follows (to achieve your nested `relative` object:

```
var root = {
    person: {
        'first_name': 'Matt',
        'last_name': 'Smith'
    },
    home: {
        relative: 'Frank'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I totally understand what you after, but do you mean this:

```
var root = {};
root.person = '';
root.home = {};
root.home.relative = '';
```

If you want to give an object extra properties dynamically, rather than just one value, declare it as an empty object literal `var obj = {}; obj.subObj = {};` etc etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to nest properties, make the variable an object, not just a string:

```
var root = {};
root.person = '';
root.home = {};
root.home.relative = '';
console.log(root);
```

If you're using Firebug, the `console.log` will pretty-print your object hierarchy.

Comment: thanks!how can js allow to root.person = []; and not root.prototype.person = [];?